# openlayers 3 IGC source from text

Tags: maps, gis, openlayers-3

I am using openlayers 3 and I am looking for a way to load track data not from urls, but directly by adding text to vectorsource IGC. I have the data with coordinates and times as arrays. What format is right? So, insted of this:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.IGC({
projection: 'EPSG:3857',
urls: [
'data/igc/Clement-Latour.igc',
'data/igc/Damien-de-Baenst.igc',
'data/igc/Sylvain-Dhonneur.igc',
'data/igc/Tom-Payne.igc',
'data/igc/Ulrich-Prinz.igc'
]
});
```

I'd like to use something like this (not sure about the format):

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.IGC({
projection: 'EPSG:3857',
text: [
array1,
array2,
array3  // or arrayall with all three arrays, or text.. What is correct?
]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more control and flexibility you can use an `ol.source.Vector` and an `ol.format.IGC` instead of the "convenient" `ol.source.IGC`. For example:

```js
var source = new ol.source.Vector();

var format = new ol.format.IGC();
var readOptions = {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'};

var features = [
  format.readFeature(text1, readOptions),
  format.readFeature(text2, readOptions),
  format.readFeature(text3, readOptions)
];

source.addFeatures(features);

var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: source});
```